# Setting up Angular2 in Tomcat7 with HTML5 push state

Tags: html, angular, tomcat7

I bundle the /dist folder of an Angular2 App as a .war file. That means the .war contains only static content. I then deploy it to a Tomcat7. This runs fine. However, when I directly access a link, e.g /login, then this throws a 404 since that doesn't exist on the server. How do I rewrite all URLs to the index.html?

I know about http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/, but since I don't have a /WEB-INF/web.xml I don't see how one would configure it.

Comment: Do you have your project separated? In other words frontend and backend as modules with their own pom? Either way you will need to use angular 2's HTTP service and `JSON.stringify` to send the object to the RestfulController. I am assuming you are using spring since you said web.xml.